# Valid regex for number(a,b) format

Tags: regex, scala

How can I express number(a,b) in regex? Example:

number(5,2) can be 123.45 but also 2.44

The best I got is: `([0-9]{1,5}.[0-9]{1,2})` but it isn't enough because it wrongly accepts 12345.22.

I thought about doing multiple OR (|) but that can be too long in case of a long format such as number(15,5)

Comment: What do you mean by _"The best I got ... but it isn't enough"_? Why not? To me, 15, 5 doesn't pass because you haven't made the decimal optional

Comment: Note to escape the dot as well and perhaps use boundaries. `\b[0-9]{1,5}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?\b`

Comment: If you only want regex tips why the Scala tag?

Comment: @PedroCorreiaLuís Because I am using Scala

Comment: @dvo it isn't enough because it wrongly accepts 12345.22

Comment: @AbderrahmenM Your regex allows `{1,5}` (1 - 5) numbers 0-9 before the decimal point. Maybe try `{1,3}`

Comment: @dvo: that won't work, because `12345` is a valid `number(5, 2)`.

Comment: @AbderrahmenM Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/RfATyQ/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Bingo! Thank you so much! Can you add an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @AbderrahmenM, Is the 5,2 hardcoded, or is that something that will be programmatically adjusted? I've updated my answer to cover this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use

```
(?<!\S)(?!(?:[0-9.]*[0-9]){6})[0-9]{1,5}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `(?:[0-9.]*[0-9]){6}` Match 6 digits
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[0-9]{1,5}` Match 1 - 5 times a digit 0-9
- `(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?` Optionally match a dot and 1 - 2 digits
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P53og0/1)

Comment: Not sure what purpose the inner non-capture group, `(?:[0-9.]*\d)`, serves. Wouldn't `(?!\d{6})` suffice? Also, any reason why you're using both `[0-9]` and `\d` forms?

Comment: @jwvh Thank you for your comment. The `\d` should be `[0-9]` indeed, I have updated the answer. If you use `(?!\d{6})`, the pattern will match `12345.22`. But the OP does not want to match more than 5 digits in total, so including the dot in the character class `(?!(?:[0-9.]*[0-9]){6})` the pattern is able to cross the `.` boundary and can match 6 digits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Scala, but you would need to input those numbers when building your regular expression.

```
val a = 5
val b = 2
val regex = (raw"\((?=\d{1," + a + raw"}(?:\.0+)?|(?:(?=.{1," + (a + 1) + "}0*)(?:\d+\.\d{1," + n + "})))‌.+\)").r
```

This checks for either total digits is 5, or 6 (including decimal) where digits after the decimal are a max of 2 digits. For the above scenario. Of course, this accounts for variable numbers for `a` and `b` when set in code.

Comment: The point and numbers after that make up the decimal have to all be optional. Like so: `...(?:\.[0-9]{0," + b + raw"})?)`. As you wrote it, only the point `.` is optional.

Comment: But this also may accept 12345.22 while it shouldn't!